# MacBook Pro : Dual-boot

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, dual-boot, grub

I need to dual boot on CleanOS on a MacBook Pro

I installed ClearOS but at the boot I only boot on the Grub, when Command key is pressed I also have OSX

I tried to install rEFIt, but without success, at the end I install it on a USB stick but only allow me to boot on the GRUB (or OSX)

Can I recover & boot form the Grub ?

UPDATE : I realise each time I do the install I have boot load not installed error [image: scrennshot]

Comment: Why didn't you use bootcamp?

Comment: his bootcamp not limited to windows? when I run the setup process, I can't do nothing with out a windows install disk

Comment: Do you mean ClearOS? You could run in VM... They also have a uEFI version of the OS available on the site for a download [here](http://mirror.clearos.com/clearos/testing/daily_iso/ClearOS-DVD-x86_64-7.iso) although it is not advised to be used for production.

Comment: Yes sorry, clearos community, I wonder will my thunderbolt to Ethernet will be recognised anyway, maybe I should just build a new server